# JNI Generated Header Yields Syntax error c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

when generating the header for JNI to begin after importing it to a c++ project it says syntax error. I have already imported the includes for JNI.

the header which yielded syntax error
[SYNTAX ERROR Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyq6N.png)

```cpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jmln_PID */

#ifndef _Included_jmln_PID
#define _Included_jmln_PID
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jmln_PID
 * Method:    l
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jmln_PID_l
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

the java class

```java
package jmln;

public class PID {
    
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("PIDIA");
    }
    
    public static native void l();

}
```

that's it I didn't get any further

Expected behavior: it compiles fine no linking error and no syntax error without the need to manually call `g++ -I<fullPath>`

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @RetiredNinja syntax error highlighted in yellow

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the text of the error anywhere in your question. Not sure what the image is supposed to be showing either.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it's highlighted in yellow text the entire method and says syntax error in eclipse what does this mean? It compiles fine after I added the win32 includes to the eclipse project

Comment: Without textual syntax errors we cannot help you.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @user7860670 "NOT ALLOWED TO EMBED FILES AT THIS TIME" so you have to click the link.

Comment: @user7860670 https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyq6N.png this was also on the post highlighted in caps and blue link text

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete Eclipse
2. Install MinGW x64 from GitHub
3. Delete old MinGW/bin from ENV path
4. Manually put MinGW/bin back in the path
5. Install Eclipse C++ it's really buggy if it has multiple languages
6. Link Eclipse C++ to the desktop and use that IDE
7. Create workspace and add any includes that were not included
8. Readd any libs like psapi to the libs path under C++ symbols
9. Readd JNI includes both `JNI/include` & J`NI/include/win32`
10. If you still see the syntax error add include C headers in the language settings it's a bug and should be set by default in C++ perspective